# DataGridView[c, r] (.get_Item()) very slow?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `RowsAdded` event to display the cells with different colors according to the values on a data grid view.

```
private void DGV_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < e.RowCount; i++)
    {
        var r = i + e.RowIndex;
        foreach (var c in _cols) // 5 columns
        {
            var cell = DGV[c, r]; // 4.5 second
            ......
            cell.Style.BackColor = .....
        }
```

However, the line `var cell = DGV[c, r];` takes 4.5 seconds to run (Diagnostic Tools) for a data grid view with about 25K rows. I tried both `DGV[intColIndex, r]` and `DGV[stringColName, r]` and there is not much difference. Is it a way to get the cell faster?

**Update:**

I found that after the APP is running, keep closing and re-opening the form and it will reduce the time to 2 seconds.

I need to draw lines between the grid view and a list box (for these rows not displaying, the line will end at the top or bottom of the grid view box). So paging will not work.

Comment: Does the end user really need to work with 25,000 rows?

Comment: Maybe use an index instead of a name lookup for your columns.

Comment: I tried both, as mentioned in the bottom of the question, it doesn't make much difference.

Comment: How are you timing this?  How do you know that one line is taking 4.5 seconds?  Is it still slow if you turn off all that drawing?

Comment: maybe `Suspend/ResumeLayout` ? *Does the end user really need to work with 25,000 rows?* , *Yes, all the rows need to be shown in one screen* ... you have to had a really f.. big screen

Comment: I set a break before and after the setting data source to get the whole time. And I also use Visual Studio's Diagnostics Tools to get the time of each line in the loop.

Comment: @Selvin, user use the scroll bar.

Comment: then user not works with 25000 row ... you know that DGV has virtual mode?

Comment: Pagination, display only relevant data based on search criteria, lazy load the data as user scrolls the grid.... You can use any of these approaches to reduce amount of data being displayed in the grid. 25K is surely not good number of rows to display. And I wonder in what use case user want to browse thru all 25k rows.

Comment: Load data page by page.